# Postgres compare each element in an array with wild cards

Tags: arrays, postgresql

I have an array in postgres that I am trying to compare individual elements using wild cards. THe following below is what I am after.

```
 SELECT '{abcdefg,hijklmnop}'::TEXT[] ILIKE '{%cde%}'::TEXT[];       --> TRUE
 SELECT '{abcdefg,hijklmnop}'::TEXT[] ILIKE '{%cde%,%foo%}'::TEXT[]; --> FALSE
 SELECT '{abcdefg,hijklmnop}'::TEXT[] ILIKE '{%cde%,%mno%}'::TEXT[]; --> TRUE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Effectively you're checking that ALL of the patterns in the second array are matched by ANY item in the first array.

It's easy to check if all the items in the first array are matched in the array of patterns (`SELECT EVERY(u ILIKE ANY('{%pattern%}')) FROM UNNEST('{values}') AS u`), a bit less so if there are cases where a non-match is valid (e.g. the first case, where item 2 in array 1 isn't matched yet it returns TRUE).

Only way I can think of doing it is to compare every individual item in the first array against every individual pattern, and say there must be at least one match on every pattern.

This is pretty ugly but it gives the correct results. (You could always wrap it in a function.)

```
SELECT EVERY(match)
FROM (
    SELECT BOOL_OR(value ILIKE pattern) AS match
    FROM UNNEST('{%cde%,%mno%}'::TEXT[]) AS pattern
    JOIN UNNEST('{abcdefg,hijklmnop}'::TEXT[]) AS value
        ON TRUE
    GROUP BY pattern
) AS matches
```

So first it unnests the arrays in order to compare each value to each pattern individually. (You could compare a value to an array of patterns via `value ILIKE ANY('{your patterns}')` but an array of values to a pattern is not possible without unnesting, I believe.)

It does a BOOL_OR and groups by pattern so we get one result per pattern; and that result is: were there any matches from the values for this pattern?

Then the outer query does an EVERY (same as BOOL_AND) to check whether every result is true (i.e. every pattern has been matched); if so then it returns TRUE, else FALSE.